# Java code to remotely deploy a war file by using DeployTask class

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war

I wrote the code below to remotely deploy a war file on tomcat server by using the class `DeployTask` already implemented by Tomcat.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "resources/StudentWS.war";
        TestClass test=new TestClass();
        ClassLoader classLoader = test.getClass().getClassLoader();
        File warFile = new       
        File(classLoader.getResource(filePath).getFile());

        String webPath="StudentWS";
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/manager/text";

        DeployTask deployTask=new DeployTask();
        deployTask.setUrl(url);
        deployTask.setUsername("deployer");
        deployTask.setPassword("admin");       
        deployTask.setWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());
        deployTask.setPath(webPath);
        deployTask.execute();
    }
}
```

And this the configuration of the user deployer on tomcat:

```
 < role rolename="manager-script"/>

 < role rolename="manager-jmx"/>

 < user username="deployer" password="admin" roles="manager-script,manager-jmx"/>
```

But I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:178)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3518)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3501)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:219)
... 2 more
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3540)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:222)
    ... 2 more
```

I would like to know what I missed or if there is a java code to remotely deploy a war file by using the url below without using maven:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/StudentWS&war=file:Path_To_War_File
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue. The problem seems to be that we needed to use the 'localwar' property. I looked through the source code, and it treats the war property differently and cannot deploy a local file using that property.
Change your code to be:

```
DeployTask deployTask=new DeployTask();
deployTask.setUrl(url);
deployTask.setUsername("deployer");
deployTask.setPassword("admin");       
deployTask.setLocalWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());
deployTask.setPath(webPath);
deployTask.execute();
```

*Update*

I just realized this only works if the server you're deploying to is local. If it's a remote server I don't believe it will work. It has to be something wrong with the Deploy task itself causing it to fail.